Clash between french babel, TikZ and usetikzlibrary{babel}
The following MWE
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage[main=french]{babel}
\RequirePackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1]{
    {#1}
    }

\begin{document}

\MyCmd{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{document}

doesn't compile unless line 5 is commented out.
I had quite a similar problem a year ago, which lead to this thread, but I'm not expert enough to work out a solution based on the answers there...
Any ideas on how to fix this?

you are hiding the semicolon in the argument of a command and so the library can't do its work. You will have to use \shorthandoff{;} before \MyCmd.

@UlrikeFischer thank you! Is there a way to avoid typing \shorthandoff{;} before each \MyCmd?

@jlab unfortyunately I get the same error when using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX on my machine (but I admit I hadn't tried before).

I have no error with lualatex nor xelatex, only with pdflatex. Maye you should use lualatex which is a more modern engine.

Is your LaTeX distribution up-to-date?

@jlab yes I think it is: MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.19 (MiKTeX 24.4), lua version 5.3.6, and MiKTeX-XeTeX 4.11 (MiKTeX 24.4).

Tested again with an up to date 2024 TexLive distribution. Works with both UTF-8 engines, lualatex and xelatex. I don't use MiKTeX. I can't say.

@AntoninBourgeois Can you show your .log file?

What do you try to do? Coding in LaTeX is not the same things as coding in classical language as your command looks like.

@projetmbc the actual command does a lot of formatting, I just removed everything to make a MWE.

Maybe another approach could be achieved. You should show a small example of what you are doing, and maybe we could propose another approach. Or not. ;-)

If you want to turn the shorthand off on every call of \MyCmd you can achieve that using an auxiliary macro. The \begingroup and \endgroup is meant to keep the \shorthandoff effect local, such that it's only active during argument grabbing, and doesn't affect anything else.
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage[main=french]{babel}
\RequirePackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand\MyCmd{\begingroup\shorthandoff{;}\MyCmdAux}
\newcommand\MyCmdAux[1]
  {%
    \endgroup
    {#1}%
  }

\begin{document}

\MyCmd{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}


Why do you put the \endgroup first? Is it not more logical to put it in the last position?

@projetmbc because you don't want the grouping to have any other side effects on the code in #1 (which we don't necessarily know, it might set a local variable and that should have an effect on anything that follows?).

Thanks a lot @Skillmon ! It looks like it works really fine, I'll do a little more testing and mark the question as answered if everything goes well :)
